# extracting a changing and unknown hashcode from text document in batch

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

i wanted to code a little update tool for a server.jar file to save me all the effort of doing it manually 
the program i'm using creates a folder which contains a file when a new update is released. this is pretty much how the program works:

```
get hash of current server.jar
find latest created folder (eg. update12)
open the file in the update12 folder (eg. update12.txt)
***extract the hash code -> %newHash%***    thats where im having the issue
compare the extracted hashcode (%newHash%) and the calculated hashcode (%currentHash%)
if they are not equal go to www.downloadupdate.com/updates/%newHash%/server.jar
download the file and replace the old server.jar with the new one.
```

the issue i am having is that i cant read out the hash in the update12.txt the file is about 36000 symbols long and in one line only

"server": {"sha1": "16f18c21286a3f566d3d0431d13aa133bebe6eff"

i want to detect the "server": {"sha1": " part and copy the hash after that
i tried many options i found on this forum but none seemed to work
like this one

```
set /p txt=<update12.txt
pause >nul
echo %txt%
pause >nul
for /f %%i in ('powershell -noprofile -c "('%txt:"=\"%' -split '\""')[1]"') do set id=%%i
echo %id%
```

just caused the batch file to close instantly
furthermore set /p txt=

if you have any solution i would be grateful to hear it

Comment: Did you run the batch file from the console window or from Explorer?  Try putting `pause` at the end or run it from a console window so you can see the output.

Comment: You are probably exceeding the [maximum command line length](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/830473/command-prompt-cmd-exe-command-line-string-limitation) and/or the maximum environment variable length (32K).

Comment: I would just rewrite the whole script in powershell.

Comment: You may be trying to read a file which uses LF instead of CRLF line endings. This could appear as one line when it is in fact multiple. Can you please confirm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off


Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
xcopy %appdata%\.minecraft\versions\%MCversion%\%MCversion%.json %appdata%\.minecraft\versions\%MCversion%\%MCversion%.text*
ren %appdata%\.minecraft\versions\%MCversion%\%MCversion%.text %MCversion%.txt

set search1= 
set search2=,
set search3=:
set textFile=%appdata%\.minecraft\versions\%MCversion%\%MCversion%.txt

:PowerShell
SET PSScript=%temp%\~tmpStrRplc.ps1
ECHO (Get-Content "%textFile%").replace("%search1%", "") ^| Set-Content "%textFile%">"%PSScript%"
Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PSScript%'"
SET PSScript=%temp%\~tmpStrRplc.ps1
echo done.

ECHO (Get-Content "%textFile%").replace("%search2%", "") ^| Set-Content "%textFile%">"%PSScript%"
Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PSScript%'"
SET PSScript=%temp%\~tmpStrRplc.ps1
echo done.

ECHO (Get-Content "%textFile%").replace("%search3%", "") ^| Set-Content "%textFile%">"%PSScript%"
Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PSScript%'"
SET PSScript=%temp%\~tmpStrRplc.ps1
echo done.
:skip
ECHO (Get-Content "%textFile%").replace("server", "`r`nlookup") ^| Set-Content "%textFile%">"%PSScript%"
Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PSScript%'"
echo done.

for /f %%a in ('findstr "lookup\"{\"sha1\"\"" %textFile%') do set "newVersion=%%a"
set newVersion=%newVersion:~15,40%
echo %newVersion%
del %textFile%
pause
:exit
exit
```

this code works for me, what it does:

```
copy the "update12.txt"
look for " " "," and ":" in the copied txt and delete the symbols
look for server replace it with a "*linebreak*lookup" 
find the string lookup"{"sha1""
trim the edges of the string with 15,40
done.
```